# GIT NO CLONA ARCHIVOS DE MASTER

Tags: git, github

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me clona correctamente , pero me clona los archivos de MAIN y no de MASTER , mis archivos estan en MASTER , alguien sabe porque no me clona , los archivos de master ?

Answer (score 0):

Esto se debe a que `master` posiblemente no es la rama principal configurada en el repositorio, por ende, al clonar el repositorio la descarga inicial no es desde esa rama.

Para verificar y/o cambiar la rama principal del proyecto ve a tu proyecto en github.com y navega en el siguiente apartado:

`Settings > Branches > Default branch`

Llegando a ese apartado debiera ser intuitivo el cambio.

También puedes usar el siguiente comando para ver todas las ramas existentes localmente y en el remote.

```
git branch -a
```

Si ves la rama que deseas, solo necesitas hacer el `checkout` correspondiente y git se encargará de descargar los cambios de esa rama en particular.

```
git checkout master
```